# Add mass action in order grid to export

Tags: sales-order, export, massaction

I added a mass action in my sales->Order grid and i wanna put an action to export the selected commands in CSV file.

I add this function for mass action in app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

```
 $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem(
    'Adminhtml',
    array('label' => $this->__('Export'), 
          'url'   => $this->getUrl('Adminhtml/controller/action') //this should be the url where there will be mass operation
    )
);
```

But i don't know how to create controller action to my custom mass action

Thank you for help

Answer (score 2):

Example for extended magento order grid:

- http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/adding-new-mass-action-to-admin-grid-in-magento/
- http://technomage.in/2014/01/add-mass-action-grid-magento/